# Angular 2+ read http response headers

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to find answer but was unable to, so my question is simple, i have this function

```
  getProducts(projectId, pageSize, page) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('/api/projects/' + projectId + '/products/?pageSize=' + pageSize + '&page=' + page).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, error => {
        reject(error)
      });
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to read pagination custom header, and in browser response i can see it, but i'm not sure how to access it with my function, on old angular i was using interceptors but on angular 2+ i'm unable to make it work, anyone can show me how to do it ?

Comment: is that Http or HttpClient?

Comment: what is version of angualr your are using 4 +

Comment: @Jota.Toledo haha, i guess we dnt have work (me and you )

Comment: Im using HttpClient, and this is latest version of angular its 4+

Comment: make use of http interceptors as you had done in angular js check this link for interceptors [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after i investigated many possibilities i found best and most simple solution, i hope this helps someone. I use HttpClient and angular 4+, just simply add new parameter in http.get methd {observe: 'response'}

```
  getProjects(projectId, pageSize, page) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('/api/projects/' + projectId + '/products/?pageSize=' + pageSize + '&page=' + page,
        { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(data => {
          const pagination = JSON.parse(data.headers.get('pagination'));
          resolve({
            items: data.body,
            totalItems: pagination.TotalItems
          });
        }, error => {
          reject(error)
        });
    });
  }
```