# Angular HTTP - Observable: How to modify tutorial code to process full response and still return Hero[]

Tags: angular, observable

Clarification for possible duplicate:  The question was intended to ask how to observe the full response and return the body; not "how to read the headers"

I'm learning Angular and have gone through the Tour of Heroes tutorial.

I'm looking to modify the code below to get the full response so I can get links out of the header and then still return Hero[].

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
    tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
    catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
    );
 }
```

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#tap-into-the-observable

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: get the full response means ?

Comment: @RahulSingh This code is getting (observing) the response body only.  I want to get the full httpResponse to extract from the header then pass along the body.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I looked at that question - that uses .subscribe(), the code above use .pipe() - I'm not sure how it answers my question

Comment: @steve i guess john links answers your question right ?

Comment: ...so what? `pipe` is just another way of composing a sequence of actions to apply to the stream. If you want that stream to be of an `HttpResponse<T>`, rather than `T`, the docs shows you how to do it *whatever happens next*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2+ read http response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997260/angular-2-read-http-response-headers)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you correctly, you want to pass additional param `{ observe: "response" }`, then you can access headers by `res.headers` and response body by `res.body`.

```
return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl { observe: "response" })
    .pipe(
    tap(res => this.log(`fetched extended response`)),
    catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
    );
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do, but setting observe: "response" breaks the code. Because a HttpResponse<Hero[]> can't be converted to Observable<Hero[]>

Comment: @steve yes, because you say your method is supposed to return `Observable<Hero[]>`, then actually return `Observable<HttpResponse<Hero[]>>` instead. Either change the signature, or use RxJS operators to extract the body as part of your `pipe`. You can't both change the thing the request returns *and* expect the signature to remain unchanged; you have to make adjustments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This "or use RxJS operators to extract the body" helped.  However, the headers are not as expected.  I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jonrsharpe's feedback, the code I was looking for is:

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {

  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(url,{observe: "response"})
  .pipe(
    tap(res => this.log("headers:" + JSON.stringify(res.headers)) ),
    map(res => res.body),
    catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
  );

}
```

I needed this "map(res => res.body)," to observe the response and still return the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
  getHeros(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    if (this.heros) {
      return of(this.heros);  
    }
    return this.http
      .get<Heros[]>(this.herosPath)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        tap(data => (this.patients = data),
        catchError(this.handleError))
      );
  }
```